# boto3 waiter for ECS ServicesStable

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am using boto3 to deploy my ECS services. I have added the [boto3 waiter for ECS](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Waiter.ServicesStable) as:

```
ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs', config=my_config)
waiter = ecs_client.get_waiter('services_stable')
waiter.wait(
    cluster="myCluster",
    services=["myService"],
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 15,
        'MaxAttempts': 60
    }
)
print("Service is in steady state.")
```

The above ECS waiter **works perfectly**, but my ECS service takes about 5 minutes to be in running state and while executing the boto3 script, we had to **wait 5 minutes with blank terminal**.

Is it possible to **print some message in terminal at fixed interval** until the waiter is complete?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use a lower Delay and MaxAttempts and put the waiter in a loop where you catch/ignore errors for the early failures and simply print a "Still waiting ..." message.

Comment: @jarmod my application takes about 5 minutes to be in running state. So, the blank terminal will be there for at least 5 minutes.

Comment: Understood. That’s why I proposed that you change the parameters so that the wait fails early, you ignore the failure, you print a message, then you wait again. Or you run a separate thread that prints messages.

Answer (score 0):

A quick review of the [waiter code](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/master/botocore/waiter.py) shows no functionality for logging status as you wait to complete.  You'll need to create your own code for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a separate thread that prints messages like below:

```py
import time
import threading
import boto3

ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs', config=my_config)
waiter = ecs.get_waiter('services_stable')

def waiter_caller(cluster_name, service_name):
    try:
        waiter.wait(
            cluster=cluster_name,
            services=[
                service_name,
            ],
            WaiterConfig={
                'Delay': 15,
                'MaxAttempts': 60
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print('Deploy failed', e)

t = threading.Thread(target=waiter_caller, args=("myCluster", "myService"))
t.start()
while t.is_alive():
    print("Waiting for service deployment...")
    time.sleep(15)
```